# How can I pull out the XML namespace prefix from an XElement object?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I have an XElement object pulled out of an XDocument object, for example

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<billpg:MyRoot xmlns:billpg=""http://billpg.com/rutabaga"" />");
XElement elem = doc.Root; /* Or any element inside the document. */
```

How can I pull out the XML prefix from this XElement object?
(In the above example for `elem` is "billpg".)

I can get the full URL namespace from `elem.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName`, but I'm trying to pull out the short "billpg" part instead. I'll also note that `elem.ToString()` returns a string that includes "billpg" in the right place which could probably be regex'd out. While this would work, its not really in the spirit of using an XML library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `GetPrefixOfNamespace()` method to achieve this:

`var prefix = elem.GetPrefixOfNamespace(elem.Name.Namespace);`

More info on this you can find in the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.getprefixofnamespace

Comment: I spent ages looking around Google for an answer and it was right there in my blind-spot. Thank you.